# Visual Studio C Program: How to print symbols for card suits?

Tags: c, unicode, playing-cards

I'm trying to make a card game and I want to use the actual card suit symbols to print cards as so:
5♣ J♦ 10♠ Q♥

Problem is I literally have zero idea how to code these symbols to print successfully in a program.

Comment: Change "Raster fonts" to some unicode font (e.g. "Lucida Console") in your console

Comment: Do you mean that you tried it (i.e. just pasting them into your source) and they weren't displayed properly?

Comment: So I changed my font  under the tools->options->environment->fonts and colors->command window, if that is what you meant.  But when I try to print say "\x06" it just shows up as a question mark

Comment: What is "\x06" meant to be? If it's an ASCII code below 32, that probably won't work, since I think those are usually mapped as control codes in terminals, not visible characters.

Comment: If it is for a console program [see here](http://www.ascii-codes.com/cp850.html).

Comment: Are you programming for Windows?

Comment: I'm using windows 10

Comment: @RyanW is it a console program (with `printf`, `scanf` etc.) ? Or is it a full blown Win32 application?

Comment: Yes, try posting some actual code...

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the unicode characters for those symbols along with a font that supports them. [This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_cards_in_Unicode) lists the unicode character code for various suits. They are:

> Spade = U+2660, Heart = U+2665, Diamond = U+2666, Heart = U+2663

This will give you black suits. There's also characters for white suits.

You'll also need to make sure you are using `wchar_t` to represent the characters, not `char` as it won't be wide enough. Also, make sure you use functions like [wprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwprintf) to do your output.

Comment: So I'm pretty new to this and I have never used those commands.  I'm trying wchar_t spade = U + 2660 and then wprintf to print like you said but nothing shows up ?

Comment: If the strings as stored in literal form, no special type should be needed. at least, I paste all kinds of non-ASCII characters into C++ source, and the compiler seems to translate them to UTF-8 or whatever is required, without me having to do anything. (Having said that, to be useful, they're converted into a UTF-8 string class and rendered in a GUI, not a terminal.)

Answer (score 1):

With Windows console font set to "Lucida Console" the following works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int i;
    for(i=3; i<=6; i++)
         printf("%c", i);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
♥♦♣♠
```

Similarly with "Consolas" font.

Comment: I'm trying this but I just get boxes? [], I made sure to change my console font to Lucida Console.

Comment: @RyanW : That possibly means your console font is set to something else

Comment: To be clear, this is run from the console window obtained by running `cmd` whose full path is `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`

Comment: I'm fairly positive I am running through the console window and I have changed the font but it still shows boxes?  I can provide screenshots

Comment: This is Windows 7. I don't know if Windows 10 is any different. I would have to swap hard drives to find out, since I have abandoned that version.

Comment: I figured it out, I guess only the Raster Font works on my computer, thank you for the help.